# Creating new array by comparing arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Can I create a new array by comparing arrays with numpy?

I have 3 arrays (`A1, A2, A3`).
How can I find all indexes where `A1 == 2 and A2 > A3` and write there the value `5` in a new array?

I have this matlab code which is doing this:

```
index = find(A1==2 & A2>A3);
new_array(index) = 5;
```

I found *putmask* and *logical_and* but not sure if this are the right tools and how do use it in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below uses `&` to chain together conditionals. As such whenever `A1 == 2` and `A2 > A3` are both `True`, the `index` array will be `True`

```
import numpy as np

A1 = np.array([0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4])
A2 = np.arange(len(A1))
A3 = np.ones(len(A1))*3

new_array = np.zeros(len(A1))

index = (A1 == 2) & (A2 > A3)

new_array[index] = 5
# array([ 0.,  0.,  5.,  5.,  0.,  0.])
```

You could use `np.logical_and` of course. But this restricts you to only two conditionals, whilst you can effectively chain as many as you like when using `&`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the np.where function

```
import numpy as np

A1 = np.array([0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4])
A2 = np.arange(len(A1))
A3 = np.ones(len(A1))*3

out = np.where((A1 == 2) & (A2 >= A3), 5, 0)
```

or more simple

```
out = ((A1 == 2) & (A2 >= A3))*5
```